# Maven through HTTP proxy not working

Tags: security, networking, maven-2, http-proxy, maven-wagon-plugin

So I have my local maven setup with the

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
     <id>example-proxy</id>
     <active>true</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <host>proxy.example.com</host>
     <port>8080</port>
     <username>proxyuser</username>
     <password>somepassword</password>
     <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

I verified my username and password are correct and that the IP and port for the proxy address is correct with the guys managing our corporate proxy.  I've tried with the DOMAIN\USERNAME and with just USERNAME, both no luck.  The guys on the proxy end say that that they aren't getting the authorization coming across.  So I tried to capture the http traffic with JMeter.  Here is a screenshot of that:

[image]

I am running

```
mvn clean install -X
```

and the stack traces is:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact d
escriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:
18 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): TransferFailedException: ClientProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a va
lid HTTP response -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could
 not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalcu
lator.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalc
ulator.java:139)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanC
alculator.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanC
alculator.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven
-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:331)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:
186)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:115)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:
pom:18 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): TransferFailedException
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:813)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:664)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:310)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:322)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:po
m:18 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): TransferFailedException
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:18
 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): TransferFailedException
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:892)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.client.ClientProtocolException
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:909)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:746)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:886)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:103
)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)

        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnec
tion.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.
java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnect
ionImpl.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:717)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:522)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        ... 11 more
```

In the past it has been:
     Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required. 
     at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:936)
     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
     at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)

I noticed I get the Transfer Failed when I'm going through JMeter to capture the HTTP traffic, but when I switch back to pointing Maven's settings.xml directly to the proxy I get the Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required

I have been able to connect to maven repositories with this same machine using say an 'XYZ' domain account which did not go through the proxy.

One other thing to add is that my proxy password is my user account from a different domain.
DOMAIN1 = Account where my proxy is using. I can't log into my local machine with this login.
DOMAIN2 = Account which I'm logged into my local machine.  This user doesn't have full admin rights e.g. not able to install programs.  We usually have to use 'run as a different user' and use our XYZ domain user to install programs.  We cannot use the DOMAIN1 user account in the run as different user for example.

I have set up maven access to a proxy successfully before with the settings.xml, and/or settings-security.xml, and also using CNTLM.  When diagnosing the problem, the proxy folks and I decided to go the simplest route and start with the clear text password settings.xml but so far no luck.  As another note I tried the CNTLM route on and it did not work in this setup.

Comment: I noticed I get the Transfer Failed when I'm going through JMeter to capture the HTTP traffic, but when I switch back to pointing Maven's settings.xml directly to the proxy I get the  Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: I resolved this issue.  It had to do with using a default password, which even though it was active was something  that the proxy didn't like for whatever reason.